# Entity Framework Core 6 TPT inheritance strategy: Change base sub type to another

Tags: c#, .net-core, inheritance, entity-framework-core

I have the following models:

```
 public abstract class SourceConfiguration
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("SourceType")]
        public int SourceTypeId { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
        public virtual SourceConfigurationType SourceType { get; set; }
    }

 public class LiveSourceConfiguration : SourceConfiguration
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }

 public class ManualSourceConfiguration : SourceConfiguration
    {
        public string MainFile { get; set; }
        public string SuccessFile { get; set; }
        public string ErrorFile { get; set; }
    }

  public class SourceConfigurationType
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Knowing that I'm using TPT inheritance strategy in .Net core 7, 3 tables will be created: 1 for Source Configuration (Base) and 2 for Live and Manual configuration (child)

Is there a way to update a Source Configuration from Live configuration type to Manual configuration? That means I want to disable the Live configuration record and insert a new record in Manual configuration with the same ID as the one in live.

The below is my dbcontext class:

```
        public DbSet<SourceConfiguration> SourceConfigurations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LiveSourceConfiguration> LiveSourceConfigurations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ManualSourceConfiguration> ManualSourceConfigurations { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<SourceConfigurationType>().ToTable("SourceConfigurationType");
            modelBuilder.Entity<SourceConfiguration>().ToTable("SourceConfiguration").HasKey(s => s.ID);
            modelBuilder.Entity<LiveSourceConfiguration>().ToTable("LiveSourceConfiguration").HasBaseType<SourceConfiguration>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<ManualSourceConfiguration>().ToTable("ManualSourceConfiguration").HasBaseType<SourceConfiguration>();
        }
```

I have tried so many solutions but none of them really worked. Here are some examples:

```
using var transaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();

try
{
    // Update SourceConfiguration to LiveSourceConfiguration
    var sourceConfiguration = dbContext.SourceConfiguration.Find(sourceConfigurationId);
    sourceConfiguration.SourceType = dbContext.SourceConfigurationTypes.Find((int)SourceType.Live);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    // Update LiveSourceConfiguration to inactive
    var liveConfiguration = dbContext.LiveSourceConfiguration.Find(sourceConfigurationId);
    liveConfiguration.Active = false;
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    // Insert new ManualSourceConfiguration without inserting into SourceConfiguration table
    var manualConfiguration = new ManualSourceConfiguration
    {
        ID = sourceConfigurationId,
        Name = liveConfiguration.Name,
        Enabled = true,
        MainFile = "newMainFile",
        SuccessFile = "newSuccessFile",
        ErrorFile = "newErrorFile"
    };
    dbContext.Entry(manualConfiguration).State = EntityState.Added;
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    transaction.Commit();
}
catch
{
    transaction.Rollback();
    throw;
}
```

```
// Create a new instance of the derived configuration
var manualConfiguration = new ManualSourceConfiguration
{
    MainFile = liveConfiguration.MainFile,
    SuccessFile = liveConfiguration.SuccessFile,
    ErrorFile = liveConfiguration.ErrorFile
};

// Remove the existing LiveSourceConfiguration
dbContext.SourceConfigurations.Remove(liveConfiguration);

// Update the SourceTypeId to match the new type
manualConfiguration.SourceTypeId = manualSourceType.Id;

// Add the new ManualSourceConfiguration
dbContext.SourceConfigurations.Add(manualConfiguration);

// Save changes to persist the changes
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

```
// Retrieve the existing LiveSourceConfiguration record
var liveConfiguration = dbContext.SourceConfigurations.OfType<LiveSourceConfiguration>()
    .SingleOrDefault(config => config.ID == existingLiveConfigurationId);

if (liveConfiguration != null)
{
    // Create a new instance of ManualSourceConfiguration
    var manualConfiguration = new ManualSourceConfiguration();

    // Copy common properties from the existing SourceConfiguration
    manualConfiguration.ID = liveConfiguration.ID;
    manualConfiguration.Name = liveConfiguration.Name;
    manualConfiguration.SourceTypeId = liveConfiguration.SourceTypeId;
    manualConfiguration.Enabled = liveConfiguration.Enabled;
    manualConfiguration.SourceType = liveConfiguration.SourceType;

    // Set the additional properties specific to ManualSourceConfiguration
    manualConfiguration.MainFile = "newMainFile";
    manualConfiguration.SuccessFile = "newSuccessFile";
    manualConfiguration.ErrorFile = "newErrorFile";

    // Remove the existing LiveSourceConfiguration
    dbContext.SourceConfigurations.Remove(liveConfiguration);

    // Add the new ManualSourceConfiguration
    dbContext.SourceConfigurations.Add(manualConfiguration);

    // Save changes to persist the modifications
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Many errors occured including:

1. The instance of entity type 'LiveSourceConfiguration' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{ID: 1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.
2. Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'SourceConfiguration' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.